# How prevent to store an identical element using "push" method?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this structure

```
$user: {
    Adressess: {
        $an_uid_generated_by_push_method: {
           street: "3455",
           zipcode: "444555666777"
        }
    }
}
```

How to prevent my firebase backend to accept another identical element in `Adressess`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to denormalize your data.  Push generates a unique stamp based on time, by the way.  Your `users` node should include uid's.  Under uid's you can put

```
street: 123 Blah Lane,
city:New York,
state:New York,
zip:94328
```

I would use a .set or .update but before that you need to look for whatever duplicate(s) you want to avoid.  You use queries for this.

Firebase queries are used:

```
var users = firebase.database().ref('users');
var street = users.orderByChild('street').equalTo('3455');
street.once('value', function(snapshot) {
  console.log('A street with 3455 does '+(snapshot.exists()?'':'not ')+' exist')
});
```

define an index for `users` in your Rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      ".indexOn": "street"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This depends on how do you define an "identical element"? If you say that in your data an element is identified by its zip code and street (simply because they're the only two properties you specified), then it makes most sense to key a collection of these elements by a concatenation o the zip code and street values.

```
$user: {
    Adressess: {
        "444555666777_3455": {
           street: "3455",
           zipcode: "444555666777"
        }
    }
}
```

This way you turn the `push()` operation into a `child().set()` operation:

```
userRef.child('Addresses').child(address.zipcode+'_'+address.street).set(address)
```

Use `push()` for collections where you don't want to access items by their natural key. If you want to access the items by their natural key (or as in this case: enforce uniqueness by the natural key), it's typically better to store the items by that natural (in your case: a composite) key.